# Is it correct and natural to say "put 10 dollars on your account in one payment"?

Tags: phrase-choice, collocations

Could you tell me if it is  correct and natural to say *put 10 dollars on your account in one payment* meaning to make the payment not in installments, but rather it's got to be one payment. For example:

> If you want your phone number to be active, you have to put 10 dollars on your account **in one payment** by the end of the week.

Comment: That sounds natural to me.

Comment: Personal taste? I'd probably go for 'in a single payment'

Comment: "If you want your phone number to remain active, you must make a $10 payment on your account by the end of the week." The word "a" means "one," but if you want to add emphasis, you can say "a single $10 payment" instead. If what you actually mean is that it must be at least $10, meaning that you will accept a payment higher than $10, just not one lower than $10, to keep it active, then you'd instead say "a minimum $10 payment," or "a single minimum $10 payment" to add emphasis to the fact that payments under $10 won't keep it active, not even if they total $10 or more.

Comment: Benjamin Harman: Thanks for the comment. It sounds like a good answer.